# How to ref when date change

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need to have counter row when date change so i have ref for the date

```
Date       Ref
01/01/2016  1
01/01/2016  1
01/01/2016  1
02/01/2016  2
02/01/2016  2
05/01/2016  3
05/01/2016  3
05/01/2016  3
07/01/2016  4
07/01/2016  4
07/01/2016  4
07/01/2016  4
12/01/2016  5
12/01/2016  5
12/01/2016  5
12/01/2016  5
```

Comment: Please! How should anyone know what you are asking here?

Comment: i need to have counter row  when date change

Comment: what counter row means? Can you explain?

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you can calculate this using `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by date) as ref
from t;
```

Comment: @Munavvar . . . The OP wants consecutive numbers with no gaps, hence `dense_rank()`.